# cURL app using Java

Tags: java, curl, javafx

Does anyone have a good tutorial on how to write a java or javafx cURL application? I have seen tons of tutorials on how to initiate an external call to say like an XML file, but the XML feed I am trying to retrieve calls for you to submit the username and password before being able to retrieve the XML feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to retrieve a XML feed over HTTP?

In that case I suggest you to take a look at [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/). It offers similair functionality as cURL but in a pure Java way (cURL is a native C application). HttpClient supports multiple [authentication mechanisms](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Authentication_Schemes). For example you can submit a username/password using Basic Authentication like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("localhost", 443), 
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://localhost/protected");

    System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
    }
    if (entity != null) {
        entity.consumeContent();
    }

    // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, 
    // shut down the connection manager to ensure
    // immediate deallocation of all system resources
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();        
}
```

Check the website for [more examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/examples.html).